# Simple PHP MySQL SELECT query grabs old data

Tags: php, mysql

I was building a simple rest api server with PHP. I am using hosting service called Bluehost. Here is my users.php file.

```
include_once('../common/include.php');
$conn=getConnection();

if($conn==null){
    sendResponse(500,$conn,'Server Connection Error');
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT `userdate`, `title`, `src`, `content` FROM user";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $users=array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $user=array(
                "userdate" =>  $row["userdate"],
                "title" => $row["title"],
                "src" => $row["src"],
                "content" => $row["content"],
            );
            array_push($users,$user);
        }
        sendResponse(200,$users,'user List');
    } else {
        sendResponse(404,$result,'user not available');
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Here is the scenario.

1. when I visit /users.php -> show right result, array of users.
2. I go to phpmyadmin and add a user -> I can verify it is added successfully in phpmyadmin.
3. when I visit /users.php again -> show the #1 result.

I am not familiar with php and mysql (I am node person :( ) and I really don't understand why it is happening. After few hours (or even next day), it starts showing update data... Here is my theory:

- maybe it is grabbing cashed data?
- maybe it still think connection is not ended...? and not showing update?

Either way, it doesn't make sense to me. I haven't touched mysql at all, so not sure mysql provides that kind of functionality by default... Also it does $conn->close(), so hmm...

Would you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just for your information, no problem with connection... also the user has all powers.

Comment: Perhaps because users <> user

Comment: @rlee Check the caching settings of Bluehost, see https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/bluerock-caching and http://knowledgebase.angiemakes.com/how-to-clear-and-turn-off-server-cache-on-bluehost/

Comment: @Progman kinda late but it was bluehost phpini setting. It was ignoring any changes. Thank you for your helps!